# autopopulate & virtual in child schema does not work

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schemas:

```
"use strict";
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    autopopulate = require('mongoose-autopopulate');

const child = new Schema({
    userUuid: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    timeStamp: {
        type: Date,
        default: new Date()
    }
}, {toJSON: {virtuals: true}});

child.virtual('user', {
    ref: 'users',
    localField: 'userUuid',
    foreignField: 'uuid',
    autopopulate: true
});

const parentList= new Schema({
    //some properties
    children: [child]
});
parentList.plugin(autopopulate);
module.exports = parentList;
```

I need the Children's list to extract a full object - but it does not work.

When I put a single user not as a child then it works well:

```
const try= new Schema({
    //some properties
    userUuid: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
}, {toJSON: {virtuals: true}});
try.virtual('user', {
    ref: 'users',
    localField: 'userUuid',
    foreignField: 'uuid',
    autopopulate: true
});
try.plugin(autopopulate);
module.exports = try;
```

This leads me to the conclusion that the problem is when the virtual is within the child schema

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the full code of my attempt to reproduce yours :

```js
const
    { randomUUID } = require('node:crypto'),
    { MongoMemoryServer } = require('mongodb-memory-server'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    { Schema } = mongoose,
    autopopulate = require('mongoose-autopopulate');

(async () => {
    const
        dbServer = await MongoMemoryServer.create(),
        dbClient = mongoose.createConnection(dbServer.getUri());
    dbClient.on('disconnected', () => dbServer.stop());
    await new Promise(resolve => dbClient.once('connected', () => resolve()));

    try {
        const trySchema = new Schema({
            //some properties
            userUuid: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            }
        }, { toJSON: { virtuals: true } });

        trySchema.virtual('user', {
            ref: 'users',
            localField: 'userUuid',
            foreignField: 'uuid',
            autopopulate: true
        });

        trySchema.plugin(autopopulate);

        const childSchema = new Schema({
            userUuid: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            timeStamp: {
                type: Date,
                default: new Date()
            }
        }, { toJSON: { virtuals: true } });

        childSchema.virtual('user', {
            ref: 'users',
            localField: 'userUuid',
            foreignField: 'uuid',
            autopopulate: true
        });

        childSchema.plugin(autopopulate);

        const parentListSchema = new Schema({
            //some properties
            children: [childSchema]
        });
        parentListSchema.plugin(autopopulate);

        const userSchema = new Schema({
            uuid: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            }
        });

        const
            Try = dbClient.model('try', trySchema),
            Child = dbClient.model('child', childSchema),
            ParentList = dbClient.model('parentList', parentListSchema),
            User = dbClient.model('users', userSchema);

        const userUuid = randomUUID();

        await new User({ uuid: userUuid }).save();
        await new Try({ userUuid }).save();
        const child = await new Child({ userUuid }).save();
        await new ParentList({ children: [child] }).save();

        console.log('User:', (await User.findOne().exec()).toJSON());
        console.log('Try:', (await Try.findOne().exec()).toJSON());
        console.log('Child:', (await Child.findOne().exec()).toJSON());
        console.log('ParentList:', (await ParentList.findOne().exec()).toJSON());
    }
    catch(error){
        console.error(error);
    }

    dbClient.close();
})();
```

Which outputs :

```
User: {
  _id: new ObjectId("62c6e7bcef50638fe0097866"),
  uuid: 'bb5af665-759a-4da0-880d-8a54ce42be4c',
  __v: 0
}
Try: {
  _id: new ObjectId("62c6e7bcef50638fe0097868"),
  userUuid: 'bb5af665-759a-4da0-880d-8a54ce42be4c',
  __v: 0,
  user: [
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("62c6e7bcef50638fe0097866"),
      uuid: 'bb5af665-759a-4da0-880d-8a54ce42be4c',
      __v: 0
    }
  ],
  id: '62c6e7bcef50638fe0097868'
}
Child: {
  _id: new ObjectId("62c6e7bcef50638fe009786b"),
  userUuid: 'bb5af665-759a-4da0-880d-8a54ce42be4c',
  timeStamp: 2022-07-07T14:03:40.902Z,
  __v: 0,
  user: [
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("62c6e7bcef50638fe0097866"),
      uuid: 'bb5af665-759a-4da0-880d-8a54ce42be4c',
      __v: 0
    }
  ],
  id: '62c6e7bcef50638fe009786b'
}
ParentList: {
  _id: new ObjectId("62c6e7bcef50638fe009786e"),
  children: [
    {
      userUuid: 'bb5af665-759a-4da0-880d-8a54ce42be4c',
      timeStamp: 2022-07-07T14:03:40.902Z,
      _id: new ObjectId("62c6e7bcef50638fe009786b"),
      __v: 0,
      id: '62c6e7bcef50638fe009786b'
    }
  ],
  __v: 0
}
```

I'm not sure what you meant about *[needing] the Children's list to extract a full object*.

If you were talking about `Child.user` then you were only missing `child.plugin(autopopulate);`.

If you were talking about `ParentList.children` then it worked out of the box for me.

Comment: In the user schema there are other parameters that are not displayed even when adding `child.plugin (autopopulate);`

When I use a single object of a user with virtual then the parameters are displayed and only when it is as an array are they not displayed.